# Problemas para recuperar dados após o redirecionamento da página

Tags: php, laravel

Fiz um arquivo para guardar os dados do cidadão em um array, pois apenas em outra etapa terei a confirmação se devo realmente armazenar estes dados

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class CidadaoStore{

    private static $cidadao = Array();

    public static function setCidadao($data){

        //dd($data);
        self::$cidadao = $data;

        return true;
    }

    public static function getCidadao(){

        return self::$cidadao;
    }
}
```

Porém se uso o get logo após o set este retorna os dados ok

```
if(CidadaoStore::setCidadao($request)){
    dd(CidadaoStore::getCidadao());
    return redirect('/enderecos/create');
}else{
    return back()->with('message', 'Falha ao cadastrar usuário!');
}
```

Mas se tento retornar o array após o redirecionamento da página este consta como vazio.

Existe alguma forma de eu obter o efeito esperado **sem utilizar** o **cache** ou o **database**

Comment: Até onde eu sei o php é stateless, ou seja cada requisição é única. Se você quiser manter o estado de algum objeto devera salvar ele com algum mecanismo (sessions, cache, database, file ou qualquer outra forma). No entanto no seu caso você pode passar por post os dados junto com redirect.  Não uso laravel mas ele com certeza tem algo assim. Exemplo return redirect('/enderecos/create', ['cidadao' => CidadaoStore::getCidadao()]). E lá na página de onde foi redirecionado você pega o parâmetro 'cidadao'.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada aqui nesse sessions, senão acho que vou como vc disse redirect('/enderecos/create', ['cidadao' => $request]); apenas dai passando o $request direto

Comment: Por que você não envia para essa outra etapa e faz a verificação lá mesmo?

Comment: Você envia os dados e lá no método envia para a próxima etapa que você quer